# Windows Installation Files from Root, BCD Error Fix?

Tags: boot, bootloader, windows-installer, bcd, bcdboot

I have a situation where I need to take the installation files of Windows 10 off the root of the flash drive and inside a new directory called `windows10x64`.

Old Directory of BCD: `/boot/BCD`

New Directory of BCD: `/Windows10x64/boot/BCD`

Old Directory of Bootmgr: `/bootmgr`

New Directory of Bootmgr: `/Windows10x64/bootmgr`

Drive letter of USB: `F:`

When booting to the flash drive while the files were on the root is fine. When booting from the files after the files being moved I am met with an error:

`File: \Boot\BCD`

`Status: 0xc000000f`

`Info: The Boot Configuration Data on you PC is missing or contains errors.`

I tried using windows bcdboot to fix this but I am new to this program and had a hard time figuring it out on my own. So my question is this: **How do I reconfigure my BCD so the paths are properly set to**  `/Windows10x64` **and not** `/` **?**

Any help is appreciated.. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Try running `bootrec.exe /ScanOs` and see if it finds your install.

Comment: Thanks, but `bootrec.exe` is not built into the installation filesystem.

Comment: Then use `bcdboot F:/Windows10x64/Windows /s F:` to fix the BCD.

Comment: That was my problem using bcdboot before. The installation has no `Windows` directory. The only root directories are `boot`, `efi`, `sources`, and `support`. Perhaps you still know which directory to use bcdboot with?

Comment: The problem is that you need a Windows directory; from TechNet: `Required. Specifies the location of the Windows directory to use as the source for copying boot-environment files.`

Comment: Can I use the windows directory from another drive (C:)? How would I use bcdboot to accomplish this?

Comment: One thing first. Is this a Windows installation on a USB stick or a Windows **installer** on a USB stick?

Comment: Second option, windows installer on a USB stick.

Comment: I see. The problem here is that all of these tools are for Windows installations and not the installer. These will not work.